Asynchronous Rust : future cannot be shared between threads safely with Redis connection manager
I am using the rust redis library to perform some operation on a database.
I have a trait from an external library that I need to implement to my struct in order to read / write values the way I should from Redis.
Here is a simplified version of how the problematic function is defined :
/// Address space.
type Address;

/// Values space.
type LocalValue;

/// Memory error.
type Error: Send + Sync + std::error::Error;


/// Address, LocalValue and Error are defined

/// Reads the words from the given addresses.
fn read_from_db(
    &self,
    a: Vec<Self::Address>,
) -> impl Send + Sync + Future<Output = Result<Vec<Option<Self::LocalValue>>, Self::Error>>;

When I implement this function like following :
async fn read_from_db(
    &self,
    addresses: Vec<Address>,
) -> Result<Vec<Option<Self::LocalValue>>, Self::Error> {

    let refs: Vec<&Address> = addresses.iter().collect();
    let value = self.clone().connection.mget::<_, Vec<_>>(&refs).await?;
    Ok(value)

}

I have the error :
error: future cannot be shared between threads safely

|
119 | / async fn batch_read(
120 | | &self,
121 | | addresses: Vec<Address>,
122 | | ) -> Result<Vec<Option<Self::LocalValue>>, Self::Error> {
| |_____________________________________________________^ future returned by \read_from_db` is not `Sync``
note: future is not \Sync` as it awaits another future which is not `Sync``
let value = self.clone().connection.mget::<_, Vec<_>>(&refs).await?;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ await occurs here on type \Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Vec<Option</* some type */>>, RedisError>> + Send>>`, which is not `Sync`
note: required by a bound in /* some trait */
|
70 | ) -> impl Send + Sync + Future<Output = Result<Vec<Option</* some type */>>, Self::Error>>;
| ^^^^ required by this bound in /* some trait */

I tried to use locks, to use copies, to free the memory, I also tried changing data types, does not work

impl Send + Sync + Future are you sure you need the returned Future to be Sync? Why so? Usually Send is sufficient for most things you would do with Futures even in a multi-threaded environment.

Looks like the question has been cross-posted to Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/1gkacjh/asynchronous_rust_future_cannot_be_shared_between/

One option would be to use SyncWrapper crate, as so:
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use sync_wrapper::SyncFuture;

trait DbReader {
    type Address;
    type LocalValue;
    type Error: Send + Sync + std::error::Error;

    fn read_from_db(
        &self,
        a: Vec<Self::Address>,
    ) -> impl Send + Sync + Future<Output = Result<Vec<Option<Self::LocalValue>>, Self::Error>>;
}

fn problematic_future() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>> {
    todo!()
}

struct MyHandler;
impl DbReader for MyHandler {
    type Address = ();
    type LocalValue = ();
    type Error = std::io::Error;

    async fn read_from_db(&self, a: Vec<Self::Address>) -> Result<Vec<Option<Self::LocalValue>>, Self::Error> {
        let better_future = SyncFuture::new(problematic_future());
        better_future.await;

        todo!()
    }
}

However, as it was stated in the comment to your question, this shouldn't be needed. Futures just need to be Send, not Sync, so the real issue is with the trait you've provided.

If the read_from_db method comes from your own code, you should be able to refactor it and remove Sync.
If it comes from some external library, you should report it to the maintainers, as it's highly unlikely it's actually needed.


Small disclaimer: part of the reason the SyncWrapper solution works is exactly because Futures don't actually need to be Sync. The Future trait doesn't have any &self methods (you need to have a mutable reference to poll on it), so SyncWrapper can safely wrap such a future without Arc or similar shared ownership structures.
